# Can Azure DevOps Server be integrated with JIRA on-premises

Tags: jira, azure-devops-server

I have a requirement to integrate Azure DevOps Server with JIRA on prem. On internet I have found integration with JIRA cloud can this be done with Jira on prem as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [TFS4JIRA Azure DevOps integration](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/42296/tfs4jira-azure-devops-integration?hosting=cloud&tab=support), it supports jira on-premises server.

Find out how this app works from [TFS4JIRA Documentation Home](https://confluence.spartez-software.com/display/TFS4JIRA/TFS4JIRA+Documentation+Home).

[TFS4JIRA compatibility matrix](https://confluence.spartez-software.com/display/TFS4JIRA/TFS4JIRA+system+requirements) for your reference.

[image]